# Order results according to most matched Criteria-solr

Tags: java, search, solr, lucene, solrj

I am using solrj api for fetch result from solr.

my query is like this:

```
  solrQuery.addFilterQuery("connection:(${user.uniqueKey()}) OR followers:
  (${user.uniqueKey()}) OR company:(${currentCompanies})")
```

I want that result first which met maximum criteria (from connection,followers, company)

i.e. if any result which fall into connection and followers and company then result should come first before that result which fall into connection, followers only.

Comment: Remember that FilterQueries doesn't affect the score. Terms in the actual query will however do that, so that queries that match more terms are ranked higher than those who match fewer.

Answer (score 0):

You might actually be better off not using a filter query so you can do something like this:

`(yourField1:value1 OR yourField2:value2 OR yourField3:value3) OR (yourField1:value1 AND yourField2:value2 AND yourField3:value3)^100.0`

You'll need to play with it a little to get the right values.

What you're doing here is telling Solr to score documents higher on an AND search, but to still return results that fit the OR search.

Comment: Actually i have total 6 field . so how many combination will be made?

Comment: @rahul Your combinations depend on what you're trying to accomplish. You should be able to add the rest of your fields to the OR subquery and the AND subquery without issue, assuming you want to OR search and AND search on all those fields.